# How to make the cropping edges hard - no automatic feathering wanted!

Tags: adobe-photoshop, crop

I've got a problem which is driving me mad on PS CS6. If I have a selection and inverse that selection and delete it, I get a feathered edge of 1 or 2 pixels on my remaining image. I want a hard crisp edge with no feathering.

The same thing happens if I take a selection which already has a feathered edge (which I want to get rid of). If I take this object, contract the selection (past the bounds of the feathering), then inverse selection and delete. The remaining image still ends up with a feathered edge.

Why is it, when I'm deleting apparently hard selected edges, that they are feathering on me?

The same thing seems to happen regardless of whether the selection was made with the marquee tool, ctrl selecting the layer thumbnail or using magic wand tool.

Any help with this would be most appreciated, Cheers!

Comment: It might be that feather tool has default 2 pixel value? Try to delete its value.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the swift reply. Do you mean the marquee tool? Feather on that is already set to 0. Is there another place where feathering default for selections is controlled? Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Before deleting, remove antialias from the tool options and goto refine edge. There select feathering =0 and contrast =100%

[image]

Comment: That's great solves my problem and it works on all of the tools. Thank you indeed! :)

Comment: Just leads to the remaining question about why rotating a layer (transform) say 60%, gives it a feathered edge in the first place...?

Comment: @Howlingbaboon -  I can answer that particular question.  When you rotate or rescale a raster image, it gets resampled, which will always degrade image quality. It's not being "feathered" as such. The image simply gets blurrier/less sharp because of the resampling. There's no way to avoid it with raster images.

Comment: @Howlingbaboon The image is a bunch of square pixels. If you rotate or distort it, the old division to pixels fit only in very rare cases to the places of the physical pixels. The new pixel colors and brightnesses are calculated (=resampling). At the edges pixels are made partially transparent because that leads to less offensive looks. If you want that look, you can remove all partially transparent pixels at the edges. Select the exterior, expand the selection 1...2 pixels, make it hard with the refine and  press Delete.

Comment: You have no idea how long I've been looking for this advice. Thank you very much.